# How to convert all the larger files and store in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created function in asp.net application

```
public static byte[] ReadFileContents(HtmlInputFile aInputControl)
{
    if (aInputControl.PostedFile != null && !aInputControl.Value.Equals(""))
    {
        HttpPostedFile myFile = aInputControl.PostedFile;
        int nFileLength = myFile.ContentLength;
        byte[] myData = new byte[nFileLength];
        myFile.InputStream.Read(myData, 0, nFileLength);
        return myData;

    }

return null ;
}
```

It is not able to convert video files and also some files. I need to convert all the files.

Comment: What do you mean not able to convert video files ? It isnt converting any file just reading from the posted file content.

Comment: Is your video file in large size?

Comment: Yes it works for jpeg png pdf ... files only but doesnot work for video and some files also

Comment: the size of the video file is 14.5 mb

Comment: @user2179026 have you tried small size video files? like 1 MB.

Comment: Yes it works for small videos but what should I do if user has to upload larger files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default the limit of a `request` is set to 4096 Kb (that is the limit for the total of the request, including all the posted files). It is possible to override this setting. It is a property of the httpRuntime and can be configured in web.config. Documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx